# Azure Functions App Runtime Worker failing on deployment

Tags: python, terraform, azure-functions, github-actions

I have an Azure Linux Functions App with a single function (for now) with a Blob Trigger. Deployed via Terraform and GitHub actions without error.

```
    function.json


{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "fsProcessingTrigger",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "aztf-test-dev-data/{name}",
      "connection": "BLOBSTORAGE_CXNSTR"
      
    }
    ]
}
```

This works fine when connection is set to `LOCALSTORAGE`. However, once deployed via GitHub Actions when I trigger the function I get the following error:

```
Result: Failure Exception: KeyError: 0 Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.11/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 495, in _handle__invocation_request call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor( ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.11/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 768, in _run_sync_func return ExtensionManager.get_sync_invocation_wrapper(context, ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.11/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/extension.py", line 215, in _raw_invocation_wrapper result = function(**args) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/home/site/wwwroot/fn_foodsecurity/__init__.py", line 16, in main print(df[0]) ~~^^^ File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4090, in __getitem__ indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3809, in get_loc raise KeyError(key) from err
```

The only suggestions I've found are to make sure it's General Purpose storage (it is). This seems like an error in the `azure-functions-host` install. Am I missing something else? Do I need to install the `azure-functions-host` in the `requirements.txt`? The Blob storage connection string is definitely correct, so I don't think it's a permissions issue. Any ideas?

Function code

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from fn_foodsecurity.functions import fs_program_etl

## add food security functions and processing jobs here.

def main(fsProcessingTrigger: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {fsProcessingTrigger.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {fsProcessingTrigger.length} bytes")
```

Comment: Please share your function code

Comment: Hi Vivek - I added the function code but it is effectively just the default blob trigger at this point. I've been trying to figure out the deployment piece before I much with changing the function itself.

Comment: As per the error issue is in function `fn_foodsecurity/__init__.py`. could you please share the code of `fn_foodsecurity/__init__.py`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to read and process csv data.

**#My Code :**

**`__init__.py`:**

```py
import logging
import pandas as pd
import io
from azure.functions import InputStream

def process_blob(blob_data):
    try:
        blob = io.BytesIO(blob_data)
        df = pd.read_csv(blob)
        return df
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error reading CSV data: {e}")
        return None


def main(fsProcessingTrigger: InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")

    read_data= myblob.read()

    logging.info (f"filedata : {read_data}")

    df = process_blob(read_data)

    logging.info(f"index 1 content is \n{df.iloc[0]}")
```

**`function.json`:**

```json
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "fsProcessingTrigger",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "test",
      "connection": "STORAGE_STRING"
    }
  ]
}
```

## `INPUT`:

**`food_data.csv`:**

```
Progam,POC,Start date
Food distribution,Vivek,2/5/2024
Food Collection,Shandilya,2/13/2024
```

## `OUTPUT`:

**Locally :**

```
Functions:

        fsProcessingTrigger: blobTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-02-13T12:07:42.291Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000116B5F66'.
[2024-02-13T12:10:41.649Z] Executing 'Functions.fsProcessingTrigger' (Reason='New blob detected(LogsAndContainerScan): test/food_data.csv', Id=a7b31b12-50fd-4002-a0e3-1a6d1b92b639)
[2024-02-13T12:10:41.656Z] Trigger Details: MessageId: bbed0a07-1105-47c6-94fe-58d7f751b1b7, DequeueCount: 1, InsertedOn: 2024-02-13T12:10:41.000+00:00, BlobCreated: 2024-02-13T12:10:39.000+00:00, BlobLastModified: 2024-02-13T12:10:39.000+00:00
[2024-02-13T12:10:41.867Z] filedata : b'\xef\xbb\xbfProgam,POC,Start date\r\nFood distribution,Vivek,2/5/2024\r\nFood Collection,Shandilya,2/13/2024\r\n'
[2024-02-13T12:10:41.867Z] Python blob trigger function processed blob
Name: test/food_data.csv
Blob Size: None bytes
[2024-02-13T12:10:41.873Z] index 1 content is
Progam        Food distribution
POC                       Vivek
Start date             2/5/2024
Name: 0, dtype: object
[2024-02-13T12:10:41.954Z] Executed 'Functions.fsProcessingTrigger' (Succeeded, Id=a7b31b12-50fd-4002-a0e3-1a6d1b92b639, Duration=485ms)
```

[image]

**Azure :**

```
2024-02-13 12:54:39.240
Executing 'Functions.fsProcessingTrigger' (Reason='New blob detected(LogsAndContainerScan): test/food_data.csv', Id=fc0706a6-d73f-495a-9d9b-e92849aa5a4d)
Information
2024-02-13 12:54:39.247
Trigger Details: MessageId: f61ff685-a91e-445b-afe1-24afa7c3f6be, DequeueCount: 1, InsertedOn: 2024-02-13T12:54:38.000+00:00, BlobCreated: 2024-02-13T12:54:30.000+00:00, BlobLastModified: 2024-02-13T12:54:30.000+00:00
Information
2024-02-13 12:54:39.331
Python blob trigger function processed blob Name: test/food_data.csv Blob Size: None bytes
Information
2024-02-13 12:54:39.331
filedata : b'\xef\xbb\xbfProgam,POC,Start date\r\nFood distribution,Vivek,2/5/2024\r\nFood Collection,Shandilya,2/13/2024\r\n'
Information
2024-02-13 12:54:39.345
index 1 content is Progam Food distribution POC Vivek Start date 2/5/2024 Name: 0, dtype: object
Information
2024-02-13 12:54:39.357
Executed 'Functions.fsProcessingTrigger' (Succeeded, Id=fc0706a6-d73f-495a-9d9b-e92849aa5a4d, Duration=272ms)
Information
```

[image]